# Is my swap partition encrypted?

Tags: 18.04, encryption, swap

I just did a fresh install of 18.04 LTS and chose system encryption from the installation menu. The system is now up and running. Using `sudo blkid` it looks like the swap partition is not yet encrypted. But I'm not sure what to look for in the output.

If I want the system to be fully encrypted, do I now need to separately encrypt the swap partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 no longer uses a swap partition but a file named swapfile on main partition. I guess it must be encrypted too. I found some information at: https://bogdancornianu.com/change-swap-size-in-ubuntu/